# CosmosDB acid transactions (commit and rollback) using .NET api

Tags: stored-procedures, azure-cosmosdb, acid

I want to write some (potentially) complex operations on my CosmosDB database, which, most importantly, can consist of multiple CRUD operations, and it is really important of course that if one of operations fails, I can rollback whole transaction. Are javascript stored procedures the only way to achieve this? Would this mean that I would write them as javascript files and execute them using .NET api (because my code is using .NET cosmos db api)? Is this possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: @Sajeetharan yes, thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are absolutely right. For the time being its achievable only through the stored procedures because it has to be run on the server side . You can definitely execute those stored procedures by calling from [`.net api`](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/stored-procedures-in-azure-cosmos-db/)

```
var sprocBody = File.ReadAllText(@"..\..\StoredProcedures\spHelloWorld.js");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need transactions within a logical partition key, you have options (nothing wrong with different document types in one collection, remember to have a property for type name to distinguish JSON-objects) 
1. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/introducing-transactionalbatch-in-the-net-sdk/ TransactionalBatch 
2. https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmosdb-bulkexecutor-dotnet-getting-started a lib for bulk insert/update operations, also supporting transactions within a partition